# Qt object not running in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application (to test) in Qt4 to start learning, but I can't even execute the object I created.
First of all, the Qt version I have is:

```
user@ubuntu:~/m_work/tests/qt1$ qmake --version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Same output if I run the command `qmake-qt4 --version`

I have a file called `main.cpp` with this content:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QPushButton button("Hello world !");
   button.show();

   return app.exec();
}
```

The commands I execute to compile are:

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
chmod 755 main.o
./main
```

And the error I get after the last command:

```
bash: ./main.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

The architecture of my laptop is x64, so as far as I know, it should work.

Hope you have some information you could tell me!

Comment: `.o` is not an executable file, it's an object file. You need to call a linker to create an executable image from your object file. Or (more likely), `make` should have created a proper binary named `main` (without an extension), try running that.

Comment: You are right. Why is that sometimes when you make a c++ program you can run the object file?

Comment: I don't know, never knew it's possible. But then again, I'm mostly a Windows guy :)

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, you should give a try to

```
./qt1
```